# Install Wordpress as a subfolder inside Laravel

Tags: wordpress, laravel

I run a Laravel based website and need to host a Wordpress blog on the same domain as http://example.com/blog

By placing the "blog" directory inside the public directory of the Laravel project, I get into an infinite redirect loop error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Adding `RewriteCond $1 !^(blog)` only works on the home page, other URL do not work ie blog/sample-page

Answer (score 4):

Add this line into the .htaccess file inside your Laravel "public" folder and it should then exclude the /blog/ so you can have your own settings for it inside the blog folder.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(blog)
```

Comment: A better solution would be to place Wordpress separately (outside of Laravel's installation folder) for the sake of security and better maintenance, and configure '/blog' path in Apache/nginx – make it point to Wordpress instead of Laravel.